# Unable to query php string value in mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

passing a query string in php but when its come to number its working fine but its come character its showing no id found where its is working fine in mysql server .kindly check the following code

Passing

```
<a  class=" btn btn-danger navbar-left" target="_blank" style="width:100%" rel="nofollow, noindex"" href="Deals.php?id=<?php echo $row['productId'];?>">View Offer</a>
```

getting

```
<?php
include 'Connection.php';
$id = $_GET["id"];
echo "id is".$id;




$query=mysql_query("select * from sdMobiles where productId='$id'") or die ("could not find ");

?>
```

and here is the page

with char 
http://sabkideal.com/Deals.php?id=MOBDXVTYVN6WCHNZ

with number id 
http://sabkideal.com/Deals.php?id=645588442716

[image]

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection attacks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Stop using the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: sql injection aside remember to use 'urlencode' and 'urldecode' if the data is capable of having a string of characters.

Comment: @danielson317 how to use this urlencode

Comment: `<?php echo urlencode($row['productId']);?>` Then on the other side: `$id = urldecode($_GET['id']);`

Comment: i just put it but  still not fetching the result

Comment: What is the actual `productId` value in the database? Guessing case sensitivity, encoding related or there is no record with the specified productid. eg: `SELECT productId FROM sdMobiles`

Comment: check the image

Comment: Remove `or die` from mysql_query and change to `if (!$query = mysql_query(...)) {  echo mysql_error(); exit; }` and update your question with what it displays.

Comment: its done thanks for all the guys